# TextView the last one and a half lines are cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

`TextView` is not showing the last one and a half lines of text. I am using `ConstraintLayout`. In `LinearLayout` it is working as expected. Tried different ways but it still argues that it won't work. Here is the whole code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.welcomeshah.dictionary.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/searchline" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchET"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Type to search"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="#222" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/backspace" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchbarlayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shadow" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wordsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffde00"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shadow">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wait"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffde00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Working on Databases"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please wait for a few moments only for the first time."
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Thanks for you patience."
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here it is an image of the layout.
[image]

Also tried adding `android:includeFontPadding="false"` but everything is the same. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Try using the `paddingBottom=10dp` for your TextView.

Comment: @Abhi I know, after adding `paddingBottom="40dp"`, I was able to see the text but that is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

> MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

So **add 0dp in width**. Try below line of code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shadow"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Can please add the screenshot of your screen

Comment: Update the question and posted the whole code of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

> I have displayed single textview in layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_constraintset_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/lake_discription"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```